# How invoke print dialog from command line?

Tags: command-line, printing, gui, dialog

I'm using xfce4 on Ubuntu. Blasted if I can't see what command will send a file to the printer via a print dialog. Please help.

Comment: `lp` is the command to print

Comment: Thanks. Like the question says, I want to send a file from the command line to the printer, via the print dialog. lp, afaik, sends direct. Yes, you can give settings *on the command line* with lp. I want to give them *in a gui dialog*. (rtfq).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gpr`:

> gpr  is  a  graphical  interface  to  lpr that provides for easy configuration of printer-specific options.

Installation:

```
sudo apt install gpr
```

Usage:

```
gpr file.pdf
```

Comment: Actually, that looks quite dated....